# Angular's route guard is not running within app

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router-guards, angular-route-guards

I've added a route with a guard on it to my `app-routing.module.ts` file like so:

```js
{path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard]},
```

If I try to completely leave the angular application then I see my expected message pop up from the `PendingChangesGuard`.  However, if I click on any other route within the angular application, then the route guard isn't executed.  How do I make it run in that case as well?

This is what the route guard file looks like:

```js
export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => boolean;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
    canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return component.canDeactivate ? true : confirm('WARNING: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back and save your changes.');
    }
}
```

and in the `DetailComponent` I did this:

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate(): boolean {
    console.info("I got called");
    return !this.formGroup.dirty;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling `component.canDeactivate` in your guard. You're basically checking if it is defined (which is always true) and then returning `true`.

Update to:

```
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
    canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return component.canDeactivate() ? true : confirm('WARNING: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back and save your changes.');
    }
}
```